# Have to run git rebase --continue immediately after git rebase branchname

Tags: git, git-rebase

In a git repository, whenever I try and start a rebase, the Terminal window hangs until I run `git rebase --continue` immediately. It looks like this:

```
$ git rebase master
git rebase --continue
First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...
...etc
```

This isn't a *huge* issue as the workaround is pretty easy, but I was wondering if anybody could shed any light on why this is happening, and if possible a way of fixing it so that the rebase starts automatically.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you able to proceed if you enter something different than `git rebase --continue` ? At first, I can think either to a broken hook or to a miswritten alias that would add implicit options to the `rebase` command.

Comment: Do you see any useful log if you run the first command with a -v verbose flag